# Specifying Prisma's database schema in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, prisma

The tables are created in default$default schema on Postgres. How changing it to public?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "schema" key on the config in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.28
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            schema: public
            host: db
            database: database_name
            port: 5432
            user: admin
            password: admin
            migrations: true
```